# Заключать ли слово в кавычки

Tags: пунктуация

Заключать ли в кавычки в таких случаях: великолепная "пятерка" игроков, "семерка" исполнителей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В обычном понимании - не надо кавычек. 
Пятерка - 6. Разг. Группа из пяти единиц.
Если это определение подходит, то кавычек не надо. 
Аналогично с другими группами, до десятки включительно, а потом - двадцатка и т. д.

Кавычки возможны как минимум в одном случае. Если это название переносится на саму группу из двух...пяти...десяти единиц. Например если речь популярных рейтингах тира "Пять лучших новичков" или "десять звезд месяца", то саму номинацию (не номинантов!) уместно назвать "пятёркой" или "десяткой", и - при необходимости - во избежание двусмысленности закавычить.

Есть еще сложные и спорные случаи. В авиации, например, возможно *атакуют "двойкой"*  - здесь "двойка" не просто группа из пяти требителей, но и стоящая за ней тактика  ("ведущий"-"ведомый"). Аналогично "двойкой", "тройкой" и т. д. могут назвать двух, трех и т.д. местную единицу (транспортное средство, технику). Тут кавычки тоже возможны, но не обязательны.

Но в целом таких случаев очень мало, в остальных кавычки не требуются.

Comment: У летчиков двойка все-таки "спарка". А в необходимость кавычек для экипажа (из n человек) как-то не очень верится.  "каноэ-двойка", ""восьмерка распашная" (это то, в чем уверен) - без кавычек вокруг двоек-восьмерок.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, конечно. Слова "пятерка", "семерка" здесь в самом обычном их значении.